# WHERE clause with MySQL LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, where-clause

I am having trouble building a LEFT JOIN query to filter out specific data.

TableA

```
+-----------------+-------------+
| name (UNIQUE)   | description |
+-----------------+-------------+
| test_1          | desc_1      |
| test_2          | desc_2      |
| test_3          | desc_3      |
| test_4          | desc_4      |
+-----------------+-------------+
```

TableB

```
+--------+-------+
| name   | data  |
+--------+-------+
| test_1 | val_1 |
| test_2 | val_1 |
| test_1 | val_2 |
| test_1 | val_3 |
+--------+-------+
```

Using the following query I get the below result:

```
SELECT tableA.name, tableA.description tableB.data
FROM tableA 
LEFT JOIN tableB
ON tableB.name=tableA.name
WHERE tableB.data='val_1'
```

Result:

```
+--------+-------+-------------+
| name   | data  | description |
+--------+-------+-------------+
| test_1 | val_1 | desc_1      |
| test_2 | val_1 | desc_2      |
+--------+-------+-------------+
```

Here is the result I am looking for:

```
+--------+-------+-------------+
| name   | data  | description |
+--------+-------+-------------+
| test_1 | val_1 | desc_1      |
| test_2 | val_1 | desc_2      |
| test_3 | NULL  | desc_1      |
| test_4 | NULL  | desc_2      |
+--------+-------+-------------+
```

Is it possible to build a query that filters like that?

Comment: how did you  get this raw `test_3 | NULL  | desc_1` ? why `test_3` linked to `desc_1` what is logic here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you put a filter on TableB in the WHERE clause, you remove all rows from the final output that have 'val_1' in the TableB.data column. If you make the condition part of the LEFT JOIN, you filter the records coming from TableB, but still get all records from TableA.

Your query would look like this:

```
SELECT tableA.name, tableA.description, tableB.data
FROM tableA 
LEFT JOIN tableB
ON tableB.name=tableA.name
AND tableB.data='val_1'
```

This will output:

```
NAME DESCRIPTION DATA
test_1 desc_1 val_1 
test_2 desc_2 val_1 
test_3 desc_3 (null) 
test_4 desc_4 (null)
```

The output you describe, with the combinations:

```
test_3 desc_1 (null)
test_4 desc_2 (null)
```

Does not seem to be a sensible output for this query, because that data isn't available in the tables, or I'm missing some information.

Comment: I watered it down for the sake of example, it makes sense with the way it works in my PHP script (matching user skills to possible user skills). Thank you for you help!

Comment: You're welcome. And thanks for accepting the answer, I just joined earlier today and this apparently gives me points, of which I didn't have any yet :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tableA.name, tableA.description, b.data
FROM tableA 
LEFT JOIN ( 
SELECT * FROM tableB
WHERE tableB.data='val_1' ) as b
ON b.name=tableA.name
```